# Dynamically naming objects to be updated

Tags: r, r-s4

I have defined an S4 Class with a slot that is a list.  I have written a method (based on Genolini's introduction to S4 - section 10.2) to append a new entry to that list:

```
setClass("MyClass",
         slots = c(entries = "list")
)
a1 <- new("MyClass", entries = list(1))

setGeneric(name="MyAppend",
           def=function(.Object, newEntry)
           {
             standardGeneric("MyAppend")
           }
)


setMethod(f = "MyAppend",
          signature = "MyClass",
          definition = function(.Object, newEntry){
            nameObject <- deparse(substitute(.Object)) 
            newlist <- .Object@entries  
            n  <- newlist %>% length 
            newlist[[n + 1]] <- newEntry  
            .Object@entries  <- newlist
            assign(nameObject, .Object, envir = parent.frame())
            return(invisible)
          }
)
```

If I then run

```
MyAppend(a1, 2)
a1
```

I get

```
R>a1
An object of class "MyClass"
Slot "entries":
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

which is just as it should be.

But in my application I will be generating the names of the objects to be updated dynamically:

```
ObjectName <- paste0("a", 1)
```

then I can turn that name into the object itself with

```
Object <- ObjectName %>% sym %>% eval
```

and then `str(Object)` returns

```
Formal class 'MyClass' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 1 slot   
..@ entries:List of 3
   .. ..$ : num 1
   .. ..$ : num 2
```

which, again, is just as it should be.

But when I run

```
MyAppend(Object, 3)
Object
a1
```

I get the following that shows that while `Object` has been updated `a1` has not been.

```
R>Object
An object of class "MyClass"
Slot "entries":
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3


R>
R>a1
An object of class "MyClass"
Slot "entries":
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```r
Object <- ObjectName %>% sym %>% eval
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. The right hand side evaluates to the object `a1`, so it is no different to doing

```r
Object <- a1
```

But this creates a *copy* of `a1`, it does not create a reference or a pointer or a synonym for `a1`.

It *is* possible to create a reference (of sorts) by passing the *unevaluated* name of the object you wish to append to your generic method. If you leave out the `eval` part of `ObjectName %>% sym %>% eval` then Object gets assigned the *name* `a1`, which can be passed as a reference to the *object* `a1`.

However, this leaves you with a new problem: `MyAppend` doesn't know what to do with an object of class `name`. You therefore need to write a suitable method for dealing with names:

```r
setMethod(f = "MyAppend",
          signature = "name",
          definition = function(.Object, newEntry){
             stopifnot(class(eval(.Object)) == "MyClass")
             objname <- as.character(.Object)
             .Object <- eval(.Object)
             .Object@entries <- append(.Object@entries, newEntry)
             assign(as.character(objname), .Object, envir = parent.frame())
          }
)
```

Now let's see how this would work:

```r
a1 <- new("MyClass", entries = list(1))
a1
#> An object of class "MyClass"
#> Slot "entries":
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1

MyAppend(a1, 2)
a1
#> An object of class "MyClass"
#> Slot "entries":
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2

Object <- paste0("a", 1) %>% sym()

MyAppend(Object, 3)
a1
#> An object of class "MyClass"
#> Slot "entries":
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
```

I think this was what you intended. You may wish to consider having a method that dispatches character strings to make this workflow easier (you would use `get` inside the method to retrieve the object from the name passed as a character string)

---

Note that I altered your own function as well; you shouldn't do `return(invisible)`, since this returns the body of the built-in function `invisible`. Just leave the return statement out altogether. You can also make use of the built-in function `append`, to make your method for `MyClass` a bit simpler:

```r
 setMethod(f = "MyAppend",
          signature = "MyClass",
          definition = function(.Object, newEntry){
           nameObject <- deparse(substitute(.Object)) 
           .Object@entries <- append(.Object@entries, newEntry)
           assign(nameObject, .Object, envir = parent.frame())
          }
)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I realised that the problem lay in that line but had no idea how to get round it. As to return(invisible()), that was copied from Genolini, so he must have thought it a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer has mentioned, the line

```
Object <- ObjectName %>% sym %>% eval
```

does not function as you intend.

If you want to work with dynamically generated names, the two functions you need to use are `get` (get an object associated with a name) and `assign` (assign into an object whose name you compute). Both have comprehensive help pages.

Pretty much nothing else will work (except for `eval(parse(text=paste0(...)))` but that is not recommended programming practice for a number of reasons.

Comment: Does the same objection apply to `deparse(substitute(.Object))`?

Comment: pretty much, yes — it's fine to use that construction for things like generating labels for plots, but for assigning values into variables it's not recommended.